# Why would USB video be dropping frames in Realtime Linux?

Tags: drivers, usb, real-time, v4l

We have a problem of losing about one frame every 60 seconds or so with four USB cameras hooked up to Ubuntu 20.04 with the Realtime Linux patches applied. From the user code `ioctl(VIDIOC_DQBUF)` call level we see that `v4l2_buffer.sequence` skips a buffer, but with no error reported. What makes it odd is that one camera doesn't skip, but three do, even though they are all on separate USB ports.

Looking at the kernel debug information we see info like this:

```
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.290354] uvcvideo: frame 1955 stats: 0/151/151 packets, 0/0/151 pts (!early initial), 0/151 scr, last pts/stc/sof 0/0/0
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.291017] uvcvideo: frame 1940 stats: 0/151/151 packets, 0/0/151 pts (!early initial), 0/151 scr, last pts/stc/sof 0/0/0
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.294264] uvcvideo: frame 1956 stats: 0/9/9 packets, 0/0/9 pts (!early initial), 0/9 scr, last pts/stc/sof 0/0/0
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.294269] uvcvideo: Marking buffer as bad (error bit set).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.294270] uvcvideo: Frame complete (FID bit toggled).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.294270] uvcvideo: frame 1957 stats: 0/1/1 packets, 0/0/0 pts (!early !initial), 0/1 scr, last pts/stc/sof 0/1217480818/18547
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.294272] uvcvideo: Marking buffer as bad (error bit set).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.294678] uvcvideo: frame 1958 stats: 0/2/2 packets, 0/0/0 pts (!early !initial), 0/1 scr, last pts/stc/sof 0/1217480818/18547
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.294682] uvcvideo: Marking buffer as bad (error bit set).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.294682] uvcvideo: Frame complete (FID bit toggled).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.294683] uvcvideo: frame 1959 stats: 0/1/1 packets, 0/0/0 pts (!early !initial), 0/1 scr, last pts/stc/sof 0/1267616628/19316
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.294685] uvcvideo: Marking buffer as bad (error bit set).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.294686] uvcvideo: Frame complete (EOF found).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.294888] uvcvideo: Dropping payload (out of sync).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.295094] uvcvideo: Marking buffer as bad (error bit set).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.295094] uvcvideo: Dropping payload (out of sync).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.295299] uvcvideo: Dropping payload (out of sync).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.295509] uvcvideo: Marking buffer as bad (error bit set).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.295510] uvcvideo: Dropping payload (out of sync).
Jan 21 08:48:52 kernel: [ 612.295715] uvcvideo: frame 1960 stats: 0/5/5 packets, 2/4/3 pts (!early !initial), 2/3 scr, last pts/stc/sof 1284525428/1284525171/19827
```

Looking at the source code, `Frame complete (FID bit toggled)` means that the USB driver hasn't sent the complete frame (otherwise we would get an `(EOF found)` message), which is backed up by the log showing `0/2/2 packets` instead of `0/151/151`.

How do I proceed with the debugging now? I find it hard to believe that the USB driver is buggy, but is there some not quite RTLinux-ready component in the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that a higher priority task or thread is interfering with your USB cameras / ports?

By default on PREEMPT_RT (or when using threaded interrupts on mainline linux) all IRQ threads will be run at 50 prio with SCHED_FIFO. So unless you've set these threads/tasks of yours to a higher priority, it's very possible that they are getting preempted by something else.

For example, linux proaudio users will always set their audio interface to have the highest priority on the system to avoid it getting preempted or interrupted by other tasks/threads... you will want to do something similar for your cameras and important tasks.

another possibility is that you have shared interrupts on one/some of your USB ports - this could cause intermittent drops, as well. you should be able to tell by viewing interrupts in procfs. The fact that you are getting drops on 3 cameras, but not on one camera -- makes me think something is shared / getting poked in the background...

beyond that, you could use ftrace to get a better look at what is going on and what functions are causing the delay / could be the culprit. possibly latencytop might also gives some hints, if you see something really out of place.

EDIT:

and these "uvcvideo: Marking buffer as bad (error bit set)" messages look suspect. -- It's possible you need to set some appropriate values for your cameras, as noted here;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155738/uvcvideo-marking-buffer-as-bad-error-bit-set

Failing that, I found a bug report here; https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207045 that has a linked patch that is supposed to fix this issue...

It still applies over linux-5.16.2; https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20200420191506.664877-1-julianmeyer2000@gmail.com/

might be helpful, if your hardware has this issue. ya never know.